# Unable to perform Keras Reshape to an input to match convolution output

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am newbie to whole tensorflow and keras. I am trying to implement icGAN in which I feed a conditional vector of length 'ny' after first convolution(I have added network architecture for better insight) . I am having trouble merging the output of first convolution with the condition vector. I tried using reshape but it gave me weird errors. Below is my code snippet. The below code does not give error but I want to know is how should I change the y which will be of shape (batch_dim, 100) to (batchdim, 32,32,100).

[image: Network Architecture]

```
    x = Input(shape=img_dim, name="discriminator_input")
    y = Input(shape=cat_dim, name="category_input")
    list_f = [128, 256,512]
    # First conv
    x = Convolution2D(64, 3, 3, subsample=(2, 2),     name="disc_convolution2d_1", border_mode="same")(disc_input)
    x = LeakyReLU(0.2)(x)

    #How to reshape the cat_input. 

    # Next convs
    for i, f in enumerate(list_f):
        name = "disc_convolution2d_%s" % (i + 2)
        x = Convolution2D(f, 3, 3, subsample=(2, 2), name=name, border_mode="same")(x)
        x = BatchNormalization(mode=bn_mode, axis=bn_axis)(x)
        x = LeakyReLU(0.2)(x)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: ... and there are no errors here.

Comment: @SeanOwen  The below code does not give error but my question is how so should I go about it. I know that in torch i can use  nn.replicate to modify the y  reshape to the convolution output. But i am not sure how to do it in keras.

Comment: @Mridul Birla. The shape change from (batch_dim, 100) to (batch_dim, 32, 32, 100). Number of total elements in tensor should be same in input and output of reshape.